# How to find Textbox of subgridview in c#

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one suggestme !!
 I have a Nested Gridview and i want valdate textbox of subgridview on submit button click i call javascript but it can't work

```js
function btnSubmit() {
  alert("Hii");

  var findGrid = document.getElementById('<%=GV_CustDetails.ClientID %>');
  var Headers = document.getElementById('th');
  var findPanel2 = Headers.$find('<%=Gv_CustEditDetails.ClientID %>');
  var findTextBox1 = findPanel2.getElementById('<%=Txt_Date.ClientID %>');
  var tt = document.getElementById(findTextBox1);
  var w = tt.value.length;

  tt.style.height = tt.scrollHeight;

  if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to Submit this Record ?"))
    return false;
    
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. Before I edited the question this was an unreadable mess

Comment: Please also include the HTML that calls this function.